# How can div maintain the same size when on mobile

Tags: html, css, user-interface, mobile

I am working on a UI that, when displaying on a mobile device, gets too small for it to be used properly.

I have the size of the div fixed in pixels, and it keeps the size if the window is resized, but when I test it on mobile mode on chrome or on a actual mobile device, it shrinks. How can I stop it from behaving like that?

Comment: Well if your div is fixed size then it wouldn't shrink. Something must be causing it and without seeing any code or example there is no way to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your page is zoomed down because it does not contain this line of code in the `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"; initial-scale="1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your code it's hard to give you the correct specifics. That said, there are two common places to start, these are:

- This meta tag will allow mobile browsers render pages in a virtual "window" (the viewport), usually wider than the screen, so they don't need to squeeze every page layout into a tiny window.

  ```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  ```
- [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) will give you the flexibility to change how your page appears at different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

in the css, set the divs min-width to the width that you want, along with the viewport meta. like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
           div#mydiv{
              min-width: <== put here the width that you want;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```